# Will MPI_BCAST broadcast the master node variable and change the slave node variables?

Tags: mpi

In the following codes:

```
if (rank==0) master();
else slave();

...

void master()
{
int i=0;
}

...

void slave()
{
int i=1;
MPI_BCAST(&i,1,MPI_INT,0,COMM);
}
```

Will the slave node broadcast "i(==0)" in the master node and set the "i" values in all slave nodes to be 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little unclear from what you've posted that you have the semantics right -- all processes in the communicator have to call `MPI_BCAST`, it's one of MPI's collective operations.  Your program would then behave as if the process designated the root in the call to `MPI_BCAST` sends the message to all the other processes in the designated communicator which, in turn, receive the message.

Your snippet suggests that you think that the call to `MPI_BCAST` would be successful if called only on what you call the 'slave' process(es), which would be incorrect.

Your syntax for the call is, however, correct.

**EDIT** in response to comment

I believe that all processes have to execute the piece of code which calls `MPI_BCAST`.  If, as you suggest, the pseudo-code is like this:

```
if (myrank == master) then
   do_master_stuff ...
   call mpi_bcast(...)
end if

if (myrank /= master) then
   call mpi_bcast(...)
   do_worker_stuff ...
end if
```

then the call will fail; it's likely that your program will stall until the job management or operating system notices and chucks it out.  There is no mechanism within MPI for 'matching' calls to `MPI_BCAST` (or any of the other collective communications routines) across scopes.

Your pseudo-code ought to be like this

```
if (myrank == master) then
   do_master_stuff ...
end if

if (myrank /= master) then
   do_worker_stuff ...
end if

! all together now
call mpi_bcast(...)
```

or whatever variant your program requires

Comment: Ok. Now if I add "MPI_BCAST(&i,1,MPI_INT,0,COMM);" to the master function as well, is my original statement correct? (Will the slave node broadcast "i(==0)" in the master node and set the "i" values in all slave nodes to be 0?)